# ImageView which overflows its parent

Tags: android, android-layout, overflow, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` which I expand (vertically) when clicked on. This `RelativeLayout` have a background image. This is implemented by adding a `ImageView` to the `RelativeLayout`.

I want the Image (and `ImageView`) to be larger than the `RelativeLayout`, so when the `RelativeLayout` is expanded the background (`ImageView`) is not stretched but instead just showing a larger crop of `ImageView`.

I would really like to have a `ImageView` larger than the `RelativeLayout` and then just expand the `RelativeLayout` instead of changing the size of the `ImageView` when the `RelativeLayout` is expanded. The reason for this is that the expansion uses a smooth animation and changing the `ImageView` for each frame leads to a significant overhead since it resizes/crops the image for each frame to match the current size of the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contained Views can't be bigger than their parents.
But the image in an ImageView can be bigger than the View.

Just don't set it as a **background** (which will be stretched), but as a **src**.

NO:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_bg"
```

YES:

```
android:src="@drawable/my_bg"
```

You can play with the `scaleType` attribute (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for fine tuning